# continuation markers in terminal visual-line-mode

Tags: terminal-emacs, wrapping, whitespace-mode, visual-line-mode

How do I get continuation indicators (a character indicator at the far right edge, normally `\`) in `visual-line mode` when I'm working in a `terminal emacs`.   FYI, the `continuation` markers on `visual-line-fringe-indicators`, do NOT work in `terminal emacs`.

I would like to differentiate between `hard` and `soft` newlines, and I would prefer indicators that are easy on the eyes.

Right now I'm using `whitespace-mode` to highlight the `HARD` newlines.  So, if I look at a line and it DOESN'T have that highlight, then it must be a soft newline.

Answer (score 1):

To get this

***Display HARD NEWLINES as RED UNDERSCOREs***

[image]

do this

1. `emacs -Q -nw`
2. Copy the below snippet to `*scratch*` buffer, and do `M-x eval-buffer`

```lisp
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (fringe-mode (cdr (assoc "no-fringes" fringe-styles))))

(custom-set-variables
 '(whitespace-display-mappings
   '((space-mark 32
                 [183]
                 [46])
     (space-mark 160
                 [164]
                 [95])
     (newline-mark 10
                   [95 10])
     (tab-mark 9
               [187 9]
               [92 9])))
 '(whitespace-style '(face newline newline-mark))
 '(global-whitespace-mode 1))

(custom-set-faces
 '(whitespace-newline
   ((t
     (:foreground "red" :weight bold)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edits to my question, and for the hard-newline  highlighting code.  Unfortunately, that's what I'm currently doing, and not what I was asking about.  I'm looking for a way to highlight SOFT newlines.  Upon re-reading, I see that my postscript about customizing was unclear.  I was applying that to the soft newlines as well.  I'm currently customizing the hard newline indicator.  Still, I think your code is useful for posterity.  I should have done that my myself.

Answer (score 1):

**BUYER BEWARE:** This is a prototype code, and during the development of this snippet, I had to re-start my `emacs` multiple times.

If the  custom fontifier doesn't move the `point` (or doesn't behave like a good citizen, in the sense that `font-lock` machinery expects it to) then `emacs` locks up the cpu, and becomes usable.  So, use this snippet only after good amount of testing.

So, don't this snippet on a buffer which has your dissertation thesis, or some such important thing.

---

1. `emacs -Q -nw`
2. Copy the snippet to `*scratch*` buffer, and do `M-x eval-buffer`.   The snippet adds `soft wrap` indicators to `visual-line-mode` buffer, just the way you want it---that is, right within the buffer, and immediately at the end of the `soft wrap`-ped line  The snippet binds `C-c C-c` `global`-ly to `visual-line-mode` for quick testing.

```lisp
;; testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode

;; testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode testing soft-wrap mode 

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'visual-line-mode)

(defface soft-wrap-face
  '((t :foreground "red"))
  "Face for hi-lock mode."
  :group 'hi-lock-faces)

(defvar soft-wrap)

(put 'soft-wrap 'display "\N{DOWN ARROW WITH TIP LEFT}")

(put 'soft-wrap 'soft-wrap t)
(put 'soft-wrap 'face 'soft-wrap-face)
;; (put 'soft-wrap 'face nil)

(defun make-soft-wrap-overlay (&optional p)
  (let* ((p (or p (point)))
         (ov (make-overlay p (1+ p))))
    (overlay-put ov 'category 'soft-wrap)))

(defun remove-soft-wrap-overlays (&optional beg end)
  (let* ((beg (or beg (point-min)))
         (end (or end (point-max))))
    (remove-overlays beg end 'soft-wrap t)))

(defun my-font-lock-matcher (limit)
  (let* ((points '()))
    (end-of-visual-line)
    (while (< (point) limit)
      (cond
       ((looking-back "\n" (1- (point)))
        (forward-char 2)
        (end-of-visual-line))
       ((looking-at "\n")
        (skip-chars-forward "\n"))
       (t
        (push (point) points)
        (forward-char 2)
        (end-of-visual-line))))
    (while points
      (let ((p (pop points)))
        (make-soft-wrap-overlay p)))
    (goto-char limit)
    t))

(defun my-extend-region-function (beg end old-len)
  (let* ((end (progn (goto-char end)
                     (re-search-forward "\n" nil 'move)
                     (point)))
         (cursor beg))
    (remove-soft-wrap-overlays beg end)
    (cons beg end)))

(defun turn-on-soft-wrap ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil (list '(my-font-lock-matcher)))
  (setq-local font-lock-extend-after-change-region-function
              #'my-extend-region-function)
  (font-lock-flush))

(defun turn-off-soft-wrap ()
  (remove-soft-wrap-overlays)
  (font-lock-remove-keywords
   nil (list '(my-font-lock-matcher))))

(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook
          (defun my-visual-line-mode-hook-1 ()
            (cond
             (visual-line-mode
              (auto-fill-mode -1)
              (turn-on-soft-wrap))
             (t (turn-off-soft-wrap)))))

(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook
       (defun my-visual-line-mode-hook ()
         (unless (display-graphic-p)
           ;; UTF-8 support
           ;; (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
           ;; (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
           (set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
           ;; (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
           ;; (setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))

           ;; (info "(elisp) Truncation")
           ;; [Truncation (GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Truncation.html#index-line_002dprefix)
           (setq line-prefix
                 (propertize "\N{SPACE}" 'face 'highlight))
           (setq wrap-prefix
                 (propertize "\N{DOWN ARROW WITH TIP RIGHT}" 'face 'highlight))

           ;; This is for wrap at the window edge
           ;; (info "(elisp) Display Tables")
           ;; [Display Tables (GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Tables.html#index-display_002dtable_002dslot)
           (set-display-table-slot standard-display-table
                                   'wrap (make-glyph-code ?\N{DOWN ARROW WITH TIP LEFT} 'highlight)))))
;; Local Variables:
;; byte-compile-warnings: all
;; End:
```

3. Do `M-x visual-line-mode`, and this is what you will see.

***Custom `soft-wrap` indicators in `visual-line-mode`; also shows wrap indicators--seen at the beginning of line--which comes by default with `emacs`***
[image: Custom soft-wrap indicators in visual-line-mode]

4. Edit the long lines; Monkey around by deleting large chunk of test, or inserting large chuck of text, or by breaking a long line by inserting newlines.  Satisfies yourself that the `soft-wrap` markers at the `right` side of text, are redrawn, along the expected lines (with old `soft-wrap` markers vanishing in to thin air)
5. FWIW, this is how the buffer looks in NON `visual-line-mode`

***Buffer with long lines; and `visual-line-mode` is OFF***

[image: Buffer with long lines in NON visual-line-mode]

---

Apropos `(forward-char 2)`---the code that moves the `point` to the next visual line:  Intuitively movement by `1` char is sufficient to get past the end of visual line `space` or `tab` character (displayed as `soft wrap`).  But once these `space` characters have a `display` property, then the `point` moves in a counter-intuitive way.  (Difficult to explain by words, and interested parties can experiment on their own, make sense of what I say here)

There are plenty of reports on official `emacs` channel and in `stackexchange`, about `display` property on `soft wrap` spaces influencing the `vertical-motion` in a counter-intuitive way.

Initially, I went with `1` and the `point` was not moving in the `MATCHER` routine.  So, `emacs` was locking up.  (Lockups are a nightmare, and difficult to debug.)

Let me repeat, consider this  code as a prototype; I recommend that you don't use it on very important buffers.

---

REFERENCES

- [`visual-line-mode`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/simple.el?h=4cf9c92e27d20da9453f9abe89d84bee5d776329#n8356) uses [`continuation` entry in `visual-line-fringe-indicators`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/simple.el?h=4cf9c92e27d20da9453f9abe89d84bee5d776329#n8385).

  There are no fringes in no `terminal emacs`, so you DO NOT get continuation markers in `terminal emacs`

Instead of `continuation` indicator---indicator that appears on the right window edge, right next to the point where the line wraps---what you instead get is `prefix` indicators---`line-prefix` and `wrap-prefix`.  That is the `prefix` indicators appear AFTER the line has wrapped, and appears on the left window edge.  (They are are NOT "user-friendly", and forces you to "wrap" your brains).

- [`line-prefix`: Truncation (GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Truncation.html#index-line_002dprefix)

```lisp
(info "(elisp) Truncation")
```

- `wrap` slot of `set-display-table-slot display-table`

  [Display Tables (GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Tables.html#index-display_002dtable_002dslot)

```lisp
(info "(elisp) Display Tables")
```

Comment: OMG.  Who ARE you?  This might be the most hard-core response I have ever seen on stack.  I won't be able to dig in and play with it for a few days, but I wanted to let you know ASAP that I am in appreciative awe.

Also, warning acknowledged.  I'll test it on an air-gapped laptop down in my bunker while the wife is out of town.  I turned my dissertation in about 20 years ago, so unless your code's destructive power includes time travel, I'm probably safe.