# How to have a right line continuation indicator on the right of `word-wrap`ped lines without "having a right fringe" and while having a left fringe?

Tags: faces, wrapping, fringe, visual-line-mode

In Emacs, I want to have line continuation indicators (the curly arrows by default) shown before or after my wrapped text (e.g. in the fringes).

However:

- I don't want want to be able to tell apart my right fringe from my buffer, either by not having a right fringe or by having it be the same background color as my buffer.
- I do want a left fringe, and I do want to be able to tell it apart my buffer, e.g. by having a different background color.

How can I accomplish this?

It would be doable if

- I could set the background of each fringe independently (AFAIU I can't, they share the same face)
- I could show the same arrow line continuation indicator on the right without having a right fringe (AFAIU I can't without a lot of custom buffer manipulation code)

Comment: originally I was just going to ask how to set the background color of fringes independently but I realized I could be an instance of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I'd say submit an **enhancement request** (using `M-x report-emacs-bug`, which is also for enhancement requests), asking to **be able to use different faces for left and right fringe**. Left & right are customizable in some ways, but not in terms of the face used. To me, such an enhancement makes sense. Worth a try.

Comment: @Drew thanks! I will.

Comment: Take a look at [continuation markers in terminal visual-line-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73954/39284)

Comment: @whitetrillium thanks, I did see that but it looks like a lot of custom and lightly tested code and I don't want to deal with potential bugs

Comment: @habit,  you can always test in a sandbox.  the screenshots should convince that it is not as bad as what it sounds like.  Anyways ... it is unlikely that you will get any more help than what is in there.